# Print 20page PDF (with 2 inch empty margins) 110% magnified (+10%)

Tags: pdf, printing

Conference proceedings and some other PDF documents often have too large magins and very tiny font. How can I print a 20 page PDF in magnified view (like it can be done on most copier machines)

(using print current view is not a good solution, must be with 1 click for all pages)

Example of a PDF: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227279197_Application_of_Process_Mining_in_Healthcare__A_Case_Study_in_a_Dutch_Hospital/file/79e41510248ac107ee.pdf?ev=prf_pub_xdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Adobe Reader XI [(Adobe Help)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7bd6.w.html#WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7bd0.w) has a custom scale option. You may need to upgrade to a new version of the reader.

Edit:
Yep, here it is:
[image: Print Dialog]